# What is the efficient way of comparing content of several text files and find duplicates in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to find an efficient way to compare the content in several text files and find the duplicate lines in them.

I started with nested loop first and it worked.

```
def process_files(self,directory):
    files=os.listdir(directory)
    files=[os.path.join(directory, file) for file in files]
    for i in range(len(files)):
        file1=files[i]
        fh1=open(file1, 'r')
        file1_raw = fh1.read()
        if i+1 <len(files):
            for i in range(len(files[1:])):
                file2=files[i+1]

                fh2=open(file2, 'r')
                file2_raw = fh2.read()

                file1_words = file1_raw.split()
                file2_words = file2_raw.split()
                for w in file2_words:
                    if w in file1_words:
                        print (w)
```

Then, I found it very slow as the files are large. So, I tried to use pool workers and finds a way around that. I tried to implement the idea mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363118/parallelise-nested-for-loop-in-ipython). However, I can't get it to work properly.

I have one requirement: 
I don't want to compare a file against itself. Which should be considered in zip.

If someone can give some idea in this matter, will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to print all the lines that are at least in two files?

Comment: If your files are so large, why not use bash `sort` or `grep` commands

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, At first yes, and eventually I want to remove them from the secondary file.

Comment: @taoufikA Could you elaborate more on that.

Comment: @Likak: what is "*large*"? Are we talking about ~10kiB? ~1MiB? ~1GiB?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, between 1GiB and 3GiB

Comment: Even if Python's multiprocessing or multithreading were efficient, they wouldn't help here. Your algorithm is not trivial to parallelise and it is inefficient (it scales bad), making a constant performance boost from parallel execution irrelevant. Can you afford storing these files in RAM?

Comment: I'm already surprised that this does not run out of memory, since you store a list of words.

Comment: Your question says "lines" but your code says "words". Which is it?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem perhaps the OP has got tons of RAM or his/her memory goes full thrashing, which would explain, why he/she never gets to the exception.

Comment: If you make `file1_words` a `set` instead of a `list` it will speed up greatly, at the cost of more memory used. You should also move the creation outside of the inner loop, since it doesn't change for each new `file2`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I would not recommend using built-in hash-tables for that, because they are notoriously memory inefficient.

Comment: @EliKorvigo reading an entire file into memory is already memory inefficient, but that doesn't appear to bother the O.P. The strings themselves will be equal in size, it's only the difference between `list` and `set` overhead that will matter; do you know what a typical ratio would be?

Comment: @MarkRansom https://stackoverflow.com/a/31153174/3846213

Comment: @EliKorvigo that was for a `dict` not a `set`, and the elements were small (integer). I'm not sure if that generalizes to this case.

Comment: @MarkRansom, about your question concerning word or line. You are right. My bad. The lines have two words separated by space; first: MD5 of the filename, second: filename.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, I need to find out if I can store them on RAM. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @Likak you would still need to modify your algorithm, because you already store the data in RAM, that is RAM doesn't solve the issue, it just lets you consider more efficient ways to deal with the issue.

Comment: @MarkRansom since OP actually stores words (short strings, which are comparable to integers in terms of memory requirements), the overhead would kill his/her RAM. `from sys import getsizeof;from random import choice;from string import ascii_letters;nwords = 10000;world_length = 6;words = [''.join(choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(world_length)) for _ in range(nwords)];getsizeof(words);getsizeof(set(words))` – I get 87624 bytes for the list and 524512 bytes for the set (almost 10x as many).

Comment: By duplicate lines do you mean exact line to line match? So you have files which contain lets say strings per line and you want to find duplicate strings?

Comment: @EliKorvigo: The overhead is higher because the goal of `set` is fast membership testing, and they're willing to pay memory for it. The actual multiplier vs. `list` is between 3x and 12x in testing, because `set`s only increase in size when the number of entries quadruples (`list`s resize more granularly). You could get lower memory usage (much lower on 3.6) in exchange for slightly slower lookups by using `dict.fromkeys` to make a `dict` where the values are ignored. `getsizeof(dict.fromkeys(words))` is 295008 on 3.6, and 393312 on 3.5. If you have the memory, `O(1)` lookups are worth it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know what a hash-table is and when/why one would want to use it :) I'm only saying, that Python's hash-tables are not exactly memory-friendly enough to store all words in two large files, though there are highly efficient implementations in other languages (e.g. sparse hash map in C++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some solutions using bash `comm`, `sort` and `awk` that will redirect the unique values of `file2` into `out`

```
comm <(sort f1) <(sort f2) -13 > out
```

If you wanna more speed use the `sort` `--parallel` option.

Using `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{lines[$0];next} !($0 in lines)' f1  f2 > out
```

file 1 :

```
I'm unique and I leave if file 1
1
2
3
4
5
I'm unique and I leave if file 1
6
I'm unique and I leave if file 1
7
I'm unique and I leave if file 1
```

File 2 :

```
1
2
I'm unique and I leave if file 2
3
4
5
I'm unique and I leave if file 2
6
7
```

Out

```
I'm unique and I leave if file 2
I'm unique and I leave if file 2
```

Answer (score 0):

By duplicate lines if you mean an exact line to line match then consider a database to which you insert an entire line as a string and check if the line exists in the database. You can try databases like MongoDB or redis